# VB How do I replace multiple characters at once?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a custom encryption application and im stuck at the replacement part.
For example I have the string `"AB12AB12"` and I want to encrypt it so that every A becomes a 1, every B a 2, every 1 an A and every 2 a B. If everything goes right the output should be 12AB12AB but this is what happens:

```
Private Sub Encrypt()
Dim str As String = "AB12AB12"
str = str.Replace("A", "1") 'now the output is "1B121B12"' 
str = str.Replace("B", "2") 'now the output is "12121212"'
str = str.Replace("1", "A") 'this is where it goes wrong, output is now "A2A2A2A2"
str = str.Replace("2", "B") 'now the output is "ABABABAB" and it should be "12AB12AB"
output = str
End Sub
```

The problem is that with this code you keep replacing everything including the previous replacement. Maybe there is an option to like replace every character at the same time so the replacements won't get replaced...

Comment: Don't do a straight replace.  Do it character by character.

Comment: There's a fairly have Doh factor here.  Don't encode with characters that already appear in the original string, you can never recover the original again.  There is no point at all in doing this, a simple substitution cypher is trivially broken with a frequency table.  Use real encryption, System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: That's not encryption buddy by any means, don't roll your own for at least anything private...

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Replace` to do the substitution, you get a string that has mixed characters that are processed and unprocessed, and you can't tell them apart. Process the string from start to end instead:

```
Private Function Encrypt(str as string) as String
  Dim source As String = "AB12"
  dim dest as string = "12AB"
  Dim result As New StringBuilder(str.Length)
  For Each c As Char In str
    result.Append(dest(source.IndexOf(c)))
  Next
  return result.ToString()
End Function
```

Note: I left the name `Encrypt` for the method, although a substitution cipher is not what is normally considered as encryption nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this fails is because if you modify str with `"A" -> "1"`, these `'1'` chars will be used when converting back as well:

```
"AB12AB12" --a>1--> "1B121B12"
"1B121B12" --b>2--> "12121212"
"12121212" --1>a--> "A2A2A2A2"
"A2A2A2A2" --2>b--> "ABABABAB"
```

Basically there are two ways to do this:

- character per character
- using a "*temporary character*"

**Character-per-character**

Here you fetch a character per iteration and translate it to the corresponding value:

```
Private Sub Encrypt()
  Dim str As String = "AB12AB12"
  Dim fmc As Char() = {"A","B","1","2"}
  Dim toc As Char() = {"1","2","A","B"}
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder(str.Length)
  Dim i As Integer
  For i As Integer = 1 To str.Length-1
      sb.Append(fmc(Array.IndexOf(toc,GetChar(str,i))))
  Next
  output = sb.ToString()
End Sub
```

**Temporary character**

If you know no `'3'` (or another character will occur, you can simply state):

```
Private Sub Encrypt()
    Dim str As String = "AB12AB12"
    str = str.Replace("A", "3")
    str = str.Replace("1", "A")
    str = str.Replace("3", "1")
    str = str.Replace("B", "3")
    str = str.Replace("2", "B")
    str = str.Replace("3", "B")
    output = str
End Sub
```

This however will slow down the performance.

---

On a sidenote, as @HansPassant already pointed out, you better don't design encryption systems your own. This one for instance can trivially be solved by frequency analysis.

Comment: Thanks alot! I am not going to use this to encrypt any serious things, this is just for fun and education.

Answer (score 0):

here i proposed a different method than you are discussed, check the possibilities

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            MsgBox(encrypt(plain_text.Text, replace_it.Text, replace_with.Text)) 
'display the result in the message box
  End Sub
```

- **where plain_text.Text: the input text**
- **replace_it.Text: the character to be replaced**
- **replace_with.Text: the character is replacing.**

following is the function used to perform the encryption :

```
Public Function encrypt(ByVal str As String, ByVal frm As String, ByVal replace As String) As String
    Dim cipher As String
    cipher = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To Len(str) - 1 'check each character separately
        If getbyte(str, i) = frm Then 
            cipher = cipher & replace 'replace the character if is same as the requested
        Else
            cipher = cipher & getbyte(str, i)
        End If
    Next
    Return cipher.ToString
End Function
```

function to get each character  in the string

```
Private Function getbyte(ByVal s As String, ByVal place As Integer) As String
    If place < Len(s) Then
        place = place + 1
        getbyte = Mid(s, place, 1)
    Else
        getbyte = ""
    End If
End Function
```